# When are two technically distinct structures really the same?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the two structures $(\mathbb{R}; \{c \mapsto 1\})$ and $(\mathbb{R}; \{d \mapsto 1\})$, where $c$ and $d$ are distinct objects. Those two structures are technically distinct, yet it would be unduly pedantic to maintain a distinction between them, and one would usually write them both as $(\mathbb{R};1)$. So, my question really is, what is the definition of the equivalence between these structures? I am not talking about merely isomorphic structures, I am talking about an even more fine-grained equivalence between structures. What is the rigorous definition of that equivalence? I used the specific example of the structure $(\mathbb{R};1)$, but I could have used some other example, like, $(\mathbb{N};+,*,0)$. I hope it is clear what I am talking about.

Comment: Same underlying set + same parameter-freely-definable (or even primitive) relations?

Comment: Not immediately clear to me what you’re talking about. What is the salient thing we have in this example that we don’t necessarily have for isomorphism? Spelling out another less trivial example may help.

Comment: You didn't specify the definition of your structure. I can tell when two groups are the same (they are isomorphic) because I know the definition of a group. The same goes for fields, topological spaces, partially ordered sets, etc. But if you don't give a precise definition of the "structure” you have in mind, there's no much one can do.

Comment: Isomorphic is usually the finest grained thing that says two structures are the same.  It means everything works the same once you rename the elements.  You seem to assume that $\Bbb R$ comes with some structure but not the whole ordered field.  What is it?  It seems you think there is some metric structure-otherwise you would need to pick at least $0$ as well as $1$ from the set and even then things could otherwise stretch and compact at different places.  Please think about the comments and revise your question.

Comment: It seems like you’re talking about equivalence up to a reassignment of symbols… I don’t think there’s a term for that since we almost never care about the precise objects that the symbols are, since that’s only meaningful if we’re trying to encode into some kind of formal system.

Comment: @jjagmath "Structure," for better or worse, *is* a technical term in model theory (which is where this question comes from). It's just a set equipped with an interpretation, in a precise sense, of some set of symbols.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, thank you.